# Чат с помощью websocket + ajax в тандеме

Tags: ajax, websocket

Я вот тут кушал-кушал, и вдруг меня осенило: а что, если сделать чат с помощью `websocket + ajax` в тандеме? Пусть через сокет нельзя передать сам текст сообщения, потому что его может перехватить злоумышленник, но можно ведь передать команду на выполнение `ajax` запроса, который и загрузит сообщение. А, ребята, так ведь можно?
То есть процесс будет выглядеть так: на сервере появилось новое сообщение, через сокет браузер узнал об этом и через `ajax` загрузил?

Comment: думаю, что вполне можно реализовать и такую схему, вот только и сообщение, переданное через ajax тоже можно перехватить.

Comment: тем не менее всё равно все c помощью COMET через AJAX подгружают новые записи и сообщения, разве я не прав?

Comment: А какой смысл держать 2 соединения?

Comment: Так я и не говорю про два. Вместо постоянных COMET испольовать Web Socket

Comment: а почему бы не передавать через вебсокет все сообщение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Пусть через сокет нельзя передать сам текст сообщения, потому что его может перехватить злоумышленник

Воспользуйтесь wss, хотя что у вас там за чат - шаринг банковских карточек или поддержка командного центра запуска МБР? :)

Лишнего удумали, ws отличный транспорт, а для поддержки старья выбирайте правильные либы, типа sockjs или socket.io.